# Can I get the current date in RFC 3339 format?

Tags: batch-file, mercurial, cmd

I am writing a batch script (cmd) in which I get the date of the changeset in RFC3339 format:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ^
  (`hg log -r . --cwd "%~dp0" --template "{date|rfc3339date}"`) ^
  do SET hg_changeset_date_rfc3339=%%G
echo %hg_changeset_date_rfc3339%       <------ writes "2009-08-18T13:00:13+02:00"
```

Is there a simple and locale-independent way to get the current date in the same format, either with cmd builtins or with an hg command? I would not like to rely on `%DATE%` because it is locale dependent.

Thanks.

Comment: are you able/allowed to run powershell ?

Comment: @Kayasax: Should be ok, but does that require rewriting the whole script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Comment: @Benoit no, you should be able to call powershell script from within cmd (powerhsell.exe -file c:\psscript.ps1),  in the ps1 format your date as suitable and export it to a file, then get the file content from cmd.  look here for powershell date formatting : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

Comment: Maybe your looking for something like [this?](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) Which you could put a wrapper around to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wmic` command to get the current Date and time without getting affected by regional settings.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do (
    IF NOT "%%~f"=="" (
        set /a FormattedDate=10000 * %%f + 100 * %%d + %%a
        set FormattedDate=!FormattedDate:~0,4!-!FormattedDate:~-4,2!-!FormattedDate:~-2,2!
        set /a FormattedTime=%%b * 10000 + %%c * 100 + %%e
        set FormattedTime=!FormattedTime:~0,2!:!FormattedTime:~-4,2!:!FormattedTime:~-2,2!
    )
)

echo !FormattedDate!T!FormattedTime!Z <--Assuming UTC timezone is used
PAUSE
```

Here is the output after executing the script:

```
C:\>dateTime.bat
2013-01-25T22:11:40Z
Press any key to continue...
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What to do if I need to delete 2 hours for example because I'm in timezone +2?